# Submit a change for review in swarm command line using perforce

Tags: perforce

I created a client using the p4 client and got the latest code. Then I did `p4 edit` to edit files. I then, created a change list with my modified files using the command `p4 change`. Now, I would like to submit my code changes for review before committing them. I believe our perforce is integrated with swarm.

Now, how do I submit these code changes using the command line?

I tried p4 help. It does not have any clue.

On a side note (irrelevant to the question): I damn hate perforce. Their documentation is very bad. And searching google for specific things on perforce leads to the bad documentation pages perforce has on its website. And all videos they have on various perforce tasks are using the GUI, not the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initiate a review in Swarm, your changelist description must include "#review" either on its own line, or separated by whitespace. Optionally you can include "@username" on or more times to require those people as reviewers.
Shelve the changelist with p4 shelve -c *changelist#*. A trigger on the server scans the descriptions, and if it sees the #review keyword it starts the review process.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the "p4 shelve" command.

Comment: I did a p4 shelve. and then submitted shelved change. But I get the message: 
Cannot submit - files are open by client <clientname> at change <change#>.

Comment: You shouldn't ask a new question in a comment. Submitting your shelf is completely different than conducting a Swarm code review of your shelf.