# Request new Swarm Review via Command Line

Tags: command-line, perforce, swarm

i want to access the "Request New Swarm Review" functionality in the P4V GUI for Perforce inside the command line. I did a lot of research but none of my attempts was successful. I tried:

1. "p4 shelve -c changelistNumber #review" like it is discussed in this post: [Submit a change for review in swarm command line using perforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905112/submit-a-change-for-review-in-swarm-command-line-using-perforce/41905392)
   In this case i get an error like: Invalid revision number 'review'
2. "$ curl -u "apiuser:password" -d"change=12345" https://myswarm.url/api/v9/reviews" like it is written in the Swarm API (https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/swarm/Content/Swarm/swarm-apidoc.html). In this case i get an error like: curl: no URL specified

Im using windows 7, 64bit

Could anyone give me a hint to point me in the correct direction? Thank you in advance! Jakob

Comment: The '#review' goes in the changelist description, not as a command-line argument to 'p4 shelve'. Use 'p4 change -i' to modify the changelist description on the command line.

Comment: Thank you very much. With your hint i could fix my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your second solution was pretty close, you just needed to make it a POST. The following worked for me:

```
curl -X POST http://*YOUR_SWARM_URL*/api/v9/reviews --data-urlencode "change=*YOUR_CHANGE_ID*"
```

Note that I'd prefer #2 over #1 because it doesn't rely on triggers.